# How to delete "end" node from a circular linked list using only tail in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, circular-list

I need to write three separate functions for node deletion in a circular singly linked list (deleteFront(), deleteMiddle() and deleteEnd()). I have to use only tail (last). For some reason, my deleteEnd() function deletes second to the last node. Can anyone please help?

```
struct node
{
    int data;            
    struct node* next;  
};

// some other functions

// 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 ->     deleteEnd() does     6 -> 5 -> 3 ->

void deleteEnd(struct node* last)
{
    if (last != NULL)
    {
        if (last->next == last)
            last = NULL;
        else
        {

            node* temp = NULL;
            node* temp1 = last;
            while (temp1->next != last)
            {
                temp = temp1;
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
            
            temp->next = temp1->next;
            delete temp1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The names `temp` and `temp1` are rather uninformative, which makes it harder than necessary to read your code. Would you consider more informative names? For example, your loop ends when `temp1->next == last`, so I suppose renaming `temp1` to `node_before_last` would be accurate? Or maybe something more succinct, but still a name describing what that variable's goal is. Then `temp` could be named something suggesting "either previous value of `node_before_last`" or "node before node before last"? It would make your code easier to reason about and debug.

Comment: `last = NULL;` isn't useful (`last` is a *local* variable), and since there wasn't a `delete last;` before it the node isn't destructed.  (Possibly a leak, or maybe not, since the caller's argument isn't modified.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your `deleteEnd` function:

- There is no way that the caller can get the new `tail` reference, because the `tail` argument is passed by *value*. The `tail` parameter should be a pass-by-reference parameter.
- The statement *after* the loop (in the `else` block) does not remove the correct node. After the loop, `temp1->next` will be equal to `last`, and it should be *that* node that is removed, yet your code removes `temp1`. You can fix this by changing the loop condition and initialise the `temp` and `temp1` variables to point to one node further in the list.
- The `else` block does not update `tail`, yet it is clear that it should, since the original `tail` node is deleted.

Less of an issue, but in C++ you should not use `NULL`, but `nullptr`.

Here is a correction:

```
void deleteEnd(struct node* &last) // corrected
{
    if (last != nullptr)
    {
        if (last->next == last)
            last = nullptr;
        else
        {
            node* temp = last; // corrected
            node* temp1 = last->next; // corrected
            while (temp1 != last) // corrected 
            {
                temp = temp1;
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
            last = temp; // added
            temp->next = temp1->next;
            delete temp1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Explanation : So we are receiving head of the Circular Linked List and taking a curr pointer and pointing it to the head of the CLL.
Then we are taking another pointer and keeping it one step before the curr pointer so that we can point that pointer's next(prev->next) to curr's next(curr->next) and free the  curr node.

```
void deleteTail(Node* &head)
{
Node* curr = head;
Node* prev = NULL;
while(curr->next != head)
{
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
}
prev->next = curr->next;
curr->next = NULL;
delete curr;
```

Comment: No explanation for benefit of original poster?

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. Still deleting second to the last element....:(
`6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 ->
1. addFront
2. addEnd
3. addMiddle
4. Display
5. deleteFront
6. deleteMiddle
7. deleteEnd
your choice: 7

1. addFront
2. addEnd
3. addMiddle
4. Display
5. deleteFront
6. deleteMiddle
7. deleteEnd
your choice: 4
6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 2 ->
`

Comment: Could you please edit and add the complete code for better understanding.